# Map one camera's colour profile to another

Tags: opencv, colors, computer-vision

I have two cameras (A & B), which I've taken photos of a calibration scene then corrected distortion and used feature mapping to get a pixel precise registration resulting in the following:

[image: Calibration scene]

As you can see, the colour response is quite different. What I would like to do now is take a new photo with A and answer the question: what would it look like if instead I had used camera B?

Is there some existing technique or algorithm to convert between the colour spaces/profiles of two cameras like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the image you provided it is not to hard to segment them to small squares. After that take the mean(or even better median) of each square in the both images. Now you have 2*m*n value which are as follow: `MeansReference_(m*n)` , `MeansQuery_(m*n)`. Using the linear color correction matrix which is:

[image]

You can construct this linear system:

```
MeansReference[i][j]= C * MeansQuery[i][j]
```

Where:

`MeansReference[i][j]` is a vector (3*1) of the color `(R,G,B)` of the square `[i,j]` in the `Reference` image.

`MeansQuery[i][j]` is a vector (3*1) of the color `(R,G,B)` of the square `[i,j]` in the `Query` image.

`C` is the `3*3` Matrix `(a11,a12,... ,a33)`

Now, For each i,j you will got 3 linear equations (for `R,G,B`). Since there are 9 variables (`a11...a33`) you need at least 9 equations which mean at least 3 squares (each square provide you with 3 equation). However, the more equation you construct, the more accuracy you got.

How to solve linear system with the number of equations  more than the number of variables? Use `Batch-LSE`. You can find great details about it in *Neuro-Fuzzy-and-Soft-Computing-Jang-Sun-Mizutan* book or any online source.

After you find the 9 variables you have a color correction matrix. Just apply it on any image from the new camera and you will got an image that look like it was taken by the old camera. If you want the opposite, apply `C^-1` instead.

Good Luck!